# Trying to use BETWEEN condition to return rows based on date but getting no results

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database containing a list of events, it is formatted something like this:

```
  Datef        Event        Location       Discipline
10/01/2012  MG Training    Brooklands          MG
```

I am running this query in order to get the results between certain dates:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE Discipline IN ('MG') AND Datef BETWEEN 01/01/2012 AND 31/01/2012
```

The query runs correctly and I know that there are relevant results in the database, but I receive no results when running the query in phpmyadmin (I just get told "Your SQL query has been executed successfully").

I was wondering if anyone had any idea why this wouldn't be returning results?

**Update:**
Putting dates in quotes (e.g. SELECT * FROM events WHERE Discipline IN ('MG') AND Datef BETWEEN 01/01/2012 AND 31/01/2012) kinda works but there's a bug.
I've certain dates doesn't work. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE Discipline IN ('COMM') AND Datef BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-29'
```

shows no results, even though there is an event on 2010-02-01. Is this a peculiarity in the BETWEEN algorithm, or am I still getting my query wrong?

Comment: What is the type of your Datef field?

Comment: what happens when you do `SELECT * FROM events WHERE Discipline IN ('MG') AND Datef BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'`?

Comment: @jcmeloni it's a text (fulltext?) field.

Comment: @The General Ok. Unless you have a really, really compelling reason to store dates in a format that isn't DATE or DATETIME, you should really think about changing the type. If you put singlequotes around your string, you will get a result, but unlikely the result you want (based on dates) because it will be an alphanumeric search against the strings-that-look-like dates.

Comment: Interestingly, this kinda works. But selecting certain dates doesn't work.
e.g. <pre>SELECT * FROM events WHERE Discipline IN ('COMM') AND Datef BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-29'</pre> shows no results, even though there is an event on 2010-02-01.

Comment: But no date in 2010 is between 2012-02-01 and 2012-02-29. Was that just a typo?

Comment: @TheGeneral glad to hear! i posted it as an answer so that you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Without quotes or anything designating those values as dates, it will simply do the math on the integers you wrote.

In other words, you ask for

```
 BETWEEN 01/01/2012 AND 31/01/2012
```

So you get 1/1=1, then 1/2012 which is almost 0.

Then you do 31/1=31, then 31/2012 which is also almost 0.

So it becomes

```
BETWEEN 0 and 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code  strtotime().  MySQL and PHP use different formatting.

For some additional info, here are a couple of links:

http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql
http://www.binarytides.com/blog/parse-and-format-dates-between-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Your column Datef is of the wrong type and should be datatime

Comment: Changed it to "date" format (I believe that datetime would only be needed if I was including times in the field).
The query still doesn't any row in which datef isn't listed as "0000-00-00".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `events`
WHERE
    `Discipline` IN ('MG')
AND
    `Datef` BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'
```